# Templating on a variable number of tagged bases

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to build a utility that involves inheriting from the same base multiple times, which I'm doing by templating on an integer to make the bases distinct. Unfortunately I've found myself writing something like the following:

```
template<size_t I>
struct X {};

template<size_t Len>
struct Y { static_assert(false, "exceeded max length"); };

template<>
struct Y<0> {};

template<>
struct Y<1> : X<0> {};

template<>
struct Y<2> : X<0>, X<1> {};

template<>
struct Y<3> : X<0>, X<1>, X<2> {};
```

Although this used to be a very common pattern in the old days of nasty C++, I can't help but feel better can be done in C++11, although the details elude me.

Can this be done succintly, for arbitrary `Len`?

(any ideas for a better title are also appreciated)

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you need this?

Comment: @hmjd It's quite convoluted, but involves implementing the same virtual callback multiple times and ensuring only one is registered at a time. I hope by building a generic utility that does that above (with implementations in the classes) I can get rid of a big chunk of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the hierarchy does not have to be flat then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

template<size_t N> struct X : X<N - 1> {};
template<> struct X<0> {};

template<size_t N>
struct Y : X<N - 1> {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<0>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<1>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<2>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<3>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<4>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<5>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<6>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<7>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<8>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<9>, Y<10>>::value << "\n";  // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<X<10>, Y<10>>::value << "\n"; // false

}
```

See online demo at http://ideone.com/wsgAhQ .

Comment: A minor downside is that the `X`s are related: to fix this make `Y`s inherit linearly, with each inheriting from an `X`, and `Y <-1>` bejng empty.  `Y` can even take `template<int>class X` as an argument instead of it being hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a bit of recursive inheritance ?

```
template<size_t I>
struct X {};

template<size_t I>
struct InheritFromX : X<I> , InheritFromX <I-1> {};

template<>
struct InheritFromX<0> {};

struct Mystruct : InheritFromX<3> { }  // inherits X 3 times
```